# Batch File write into .txt does not work but works in a CMD Window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a strange problem. Maybe its just me but I dont get it... I have a Batch file with some Stuff and everything is working instead of 1 thing...

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices" | findstr /i "\\dc\BR-TRIWO-Küche-Farbe" > u:\tmplog.txt
```

if I copy and paste this Line into a CMD Window (no admin rights) it will write the output as expected into the File tmplog.txt

But if I run the Batch file, it creates an empty file... Don't know what's wrong and why it's working manually but not inside the Batch file...

Maybe you guys have an Idea :)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you're going to use `findstr` then please take a look at its usage information, and use either different option, or escape the appropriate characters. Alternatively use `find` instead. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. You can do the same thing using `find /?` too. Your current post does not idicate that you have read the usage information before posting your question, and that should have been the first thing you did. The backward slash is an escape character in a `findstr` regular expression, and regular expressions are a default option.

Comment: There is an `ü` in the code, so the encoding of the batch file might be wrong; what is returned when you type `type "D:\path\to\your\script.bat"` in a Command Prompt window?

Comment: I´m using the right encoding that was a thought from me, but thank you for the idea :D